# Rubymine 30 day trial, early uninstallation

Tags: rubymine

If I uninstall Rubymine before the 30 day trial expires will I be able to use the trial again in the future? I've only had it for a day and am concerned that I will lose access to try it out for free if I uninstall it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will remember the initial install and expires after 30 days.  You can email sales@jetbrains.com to request an extension for the trial period.